# Nuxt breaks after hard refresh

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

So, I set up a website using Nuxt 2 and there is something odd going on with it. I set up my site without using trailing slashes (router options). On refresh the server adds a trailing slash anyway. Normally that wouldn't be a problem, because both pages would just work, but now it just breaks and tells me te page doesn't exist. I have an exact same site with the exact same versions of Nuxt and everything else and that one keeps working on refresh, even with trailing slash.

Setup:

- Nuxt 2.18
- Static
- SRR false
- Router options trailingSlash, false
- htaccess is now empty again (to test)

I have tried the following things:

- Putting trailing slashes on through Nuxt, htaccess and href's.
- Set up htaccess to remove trailing slash
- Regenerating the site multiple times

None of these solutions seem to work. And it's a pretty big issue, because Google is looking for the sites WITH trailing slash to crawl and index, which now return a soft404, so no indexing whatsoever.

The website is https://expanddigital.nl

I hope someone here found a solution to the problem!

Comment: Where is your website hosted? This can be an issue too. Also a Github link is welcome here. Does it behave in the same way if you generate it locally?

Comment: @kissu It is hosted at TransIP. I can't share a GitHub repository unfortunately. It does NOT do it locally, so it is a server related issue for sure, not Nuxt related. I just can't seem to fix it. Also, the other site is hosted at the exact same server and that one does work with trailing slashes.

Comment: Can't help more so. Why do you want to mess up with trailing slashes anyway?

Comment: I don't want to, it just happens. For me personaly it doesn't matter if it's with or without.  But somehow this specific website decided to break when there are trailing slashes.

Comment: Just use the default so: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-router#example-behavior-with-child-routes

Comment: That does work indeed, but the problem with that is double URL's in for example Google Analytics. Not really great for data collection, nor SEO.

Comment: I'm not sure that this one is an issue per se last time I checked that subject. It's not a big deal because Google will consider the 2 (w/ or wo/) as 1. Also, you can always make a 302 or alike from the `without` to the `with`.

Comment: Thank you good sir! That's really good to know. I'll just put the 302's in place and I am good to go!

Comment: Tell me when you're done, I'll post a quick answer if it's working great.

Comment: Unfortunately the redirect (both 301 and 302) cause a 'too many redirects' error, thus creating a loop breaking the website. I guess I will just have to do with duplicate pages in Analytics for now, until I come across another fix.

Comment: Hm, the redirect would be more of an `.htaccess` or Apache configuration IMO. Also, check this article for an official source saying that it doesn't really matter: https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2010/04/to-slash-or-not-to-slash?hl=en And a few ways to fix that. Otherwise, a server configuration is also a good approach overall for sure.

Comment: I did the redirects in .htacces which created the loop. Unfortunately the website is on a non-configurable server, so maybe I will move it to another.

Comment: Not sure how to create it properly but there is probably a way to check if it does have a trailing slash or not. Still, check the linked article for some other nice info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using the [default behavior](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-router/#example-behavior-with-child-routes) for Nuxt's `trailingSlash` setting.

Google [doesn't really care](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2010/04/to-slash-or-not-to-slash?hl=en#different-content-on-slash-and-non-slash-urls-is-okay-for-google,-but-often-is-less-ideal-for-users) about having them both at the same time, and this blog post is from 2010 but I guess it's even more okay nowadays.

There are several [possible approaches](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2010/04/to-slash-or-not-to-slash?hl=en#steps-for-serving-only-one-url-version) suggested by the article. Maybe a server configuration could forward the non trailing into some trailing slashes those too, but it's nothing to worry too much about overall.